# creating a debugfs file that is used to read/write u32 value

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, debugfs

I'm trying to create a file with the following specifications.

> The file "myfile" in a debugfs sub-directory is to be **read only** by any user, and when read,
> should return the current value of the jiffies kernel timer.

I have written the following line of code in the function `my_init` that is directly called through `module_init(my_init)`.

```
if (!debugfs_create_u32("myfile", 0444, handle, (u32*)&myfile))
        goto fail;
```

when run `make`, i get the following error.

```
error: invalid use of void expression
  if (!debugfs_create_u32("myfile", 0444, handle, (u32*)&myfile))
```

It would br great if somebody can help me clear this error.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The `debugfs_create_u32` function should return a `struct dentry *`. Are you sure the compiler sees the correct prototype for this function? I.e. you are using the correct include file, and you do not declare the function in your own code?

Comment: Thank you for responding, I've used ```#include <linux/debugfs.h>```

Comment: Can someone please help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is returning -enodev. so instead of using ! you can use IS_ERR .

Comment: @JohanMyréen I've included ```module.h, fs.h, poll.h, errno.h, debugfs.h, jiffies.h, semaphores.h```. I was able to get rid of this issue by eliminating that check but I believe it might result in unwanted warnings in other use cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value was removed from `debugfs_create_u32` at [2b07021a940ce1cdec736ec0cacad6af77717afc](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux/commit/2b07021a940ce1cdec736ec0cacad6af77717afc) which went into v5.7:

> debugfs: remove return value of debugfs_create_u32()
> No one checks the return value of debugfs_create_u32(), as it's not
> needed, so make the return value void, so that no one tries to do so in
> the future.

so you can just get rid of that `if`.

The problem for me is that I wanted to remove the debugfs file afterwards at module unload, and my entry was on the debugfs toplevel with NULL, so I can't just `debugfs_remove_recursive`.

So I think I will just get the dentry with:

```
debugfs_lookup("basename", NULL)
```

Maybe we are just not supposed to create debugfs entries on toplevel, as it pollutes namespaces too much if you have more than one.

It is a bit inconsistent that some very similar calls still return the file however, e.g.:

```
struct dentry *debugfs_create_ulong
```

so I think this was just an API mistake. Are kernel devs not perfect Gods as I once though? :-O